# Создание shared библиотек на Linux gcc

Tags: c, gcc, библиотеки

У меня проблема в понимании создания so библиотек с версиями.
Значит задача такова сделать программу `main` и к ней библиотеку `libcommon.so.1.0`

У меня есть вопрос. Вот я запустил make и библиотека собирается так:

```
CC=gcc
HOME_LIBPATH=/home/cj/lib
OBJECTS=libcommon.o 

$(CC) -shared -Wl,-rpath,$(HOME_LIBPATH),-soname,libcommon.so.1  -o $(HOME_LIBPATH)/libcommon.so.1.0 $(OBJECTS) -lm
```

Далее у меня идут сборка программы:

```
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-write-strings
HOME_LIBPATH=/home/cj/lib
LIB= -lcommon
HOME_LIBPATH=/home/cj/lib
WL=-Wl,-rpath,$(HOME_LIBPATH)
LIBPATH=-L $(HOME_LIBPATH)

$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(WL) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LIBPATH)  $(LIB)
```

И тут возникает проблема! [image: Error]

Решение этой проблемы создать ссылку на библиотеку **именно в этом же каталоге где и библиотека.** Но с расширением **so**

```
ln -s /home/cj/lib/libcommon.so.1.0 /home/cj/lib/libcommon.so
```

После этого компиляция проходит отлично! Но программа теперь не может найти `libcommon.so.1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я опять дела. ссылку только теперь с **so.1**

```
ln -s /home/cj/lib/libcommon.so.1.0 /home/cj/lib/libcommon.so.1
```

И только после этого все отрабатывает!

Вопросы!

1. Почему при компиляции требуется `libcommon.so`, а не
   `libcommon.so.1` ?
2. Почему все 3 файла `libcommon.so.1.0`
       `libcommon.so.1` `libcommon.so` должны лежать в одном каталоге? Я не
       могу сделать так что бы `libcommon.so.1.0` лежал где попало а
       остальные ссылались на него, так тоже ошибка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 При компиляции можно указать относительное имя -lcommon тогда компилятор сам подставит libcommon.so или указать полное имя libcommon.so (libcommon.so.1)

2 Вариантов расположения файлов библиотеки может быть очень много. Но лучше чтобы они находились в одном каталоге так меньше прописывать путей для запуска программы. Но в основном это делается для возможности иметь несколько версий одной библиотеки.
Пример :
 у вас есть три версии  libcommon.so.1 libcommon.so.2 libcommon.so.3 
 и основная ссылка libcommon.so указывает на libcommon.so.3 и все программы используют 3 версию , но можно скомпилировать отдельную программу и указать чтобы чтобы использовалась 2 версию

Comment: -lcommon У меня так и указанно! Но при компиляции gcc просит libcommon.so, хотя должен libcommon.so.1

Comment: Если нужно собрать с конкретной библиотекой нужно указать libcommon.so.1

Comment: Добавляю -llibcommon.so, в ответ ld cannot find -llibcommon.so

Comment: Не  -llibcommon.so , а просто libcommon.so.1